# connection refused when showmount but I can connected to nfs server using mount

Tags: networking, nfs, vpn

That's weird that I can't check showmount of an nfs server. But I can connected to the nfs client.
**I can read and write file from client side in mounted point**

```
# mounting in client
mount -t nfs 100.96.0.16:/delme /root/tmp
```

## Here is all possible configurations

###### in server:/etc/exports

```
/delme 100.96.0.0/12(rw,async,no_root_squash,insecure,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
```

###### ifconfig  in server

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 ****1  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 ****1  prefixlen 112  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 00:16:3e:c1:29:a2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 16592  bytes 2976190 (2.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8357  bytes 1480084 (1.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 40  bytes 2716 (2.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 40  bytes 2716 (2.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

warp: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1400
        inet 172.16.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 172.16.0.2
        inet6 2606:4700:110:8c25:8c68:2998:abd9:bb8e  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::991c:c43c:5ac9:a519  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 276  bytes 38332 (38.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 236  bytes 30651 (30.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

###### ifconfig  in client

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 ***2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 ***2  prefixlen 112  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 00:16:3e:02:e7:57  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14726  bytes 2491233 (2.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7028  bytes 1170140 (1.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 80  bytes 7360 (7.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 80  bytes 7360 (7.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

warp: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1400
        inet 172.16.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 172.16.0.2
        inet6 2606:4700:110:8ec1:dda1:c327:5e42:f963  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::1101:189e:d0dc:edae  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 281  bytes 53356 (53.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 385  bytes 42565 (42.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Note that I'm using **VPN Zero Trust Cloudflare**

###### netstat tulpn | grep rpc

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:41783           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3947/rpc.mountd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50045           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3947/rpc.mountd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:56385           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3947/rpc.mountd
tcp6       0      0 :::53185                :::*                    LISTEN      3947/rpc.mountd
tcp6       0      0 :::55553                :::*                    LISTEN      3947/rpc.mountd
tcp6       0      0 :::41201                :::*                    LISTEN      3947/rpc.mountd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:40165           0.0.0.0:*                           3947/rpc.mountd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44333           0.0.0.0:*                           3947/rpc.mountd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42809           0.0.0.0:*                           3947/rpc.mountd
udp6       0      0 :::53483                :::*                                3947/rpc.mountd
udp6       0      0 :::49717                :::*                                3947/rpc.mountd
udp6       0      0 :::44615                :::*                                3947/rpc.mountd
```

The weird is, it returns the result for showmount in client when I access it with public IPv6

```
root@client:~/tmp# showmount -e 100.96.0.16
rpc mount export: RPC: Unable to receive; errno = Connection refused
root@client:~/tmp# showmount -e <my server public ipv6>
Export list for <my server public ipv6>:
/delme 100.96.0.0/12
root@client:~/tmp# ls /root/tmp
this_file_was_generated_from_server
root@client:~/tmp# touch foo && ls /root/tmp
foo  this_file_was_generated_from_server
root@client:~/tmp#
```

Note that, since I'm using zero trust in interface named *warp* from cloudflare that related with **172.16.0.2**:

- 100.96.0.16 is private IP for server
- 100.96.0.17 is private IP for client

Therefore I can ping the server from client side:

```
root@client:~# ping 100.96.0.16 -I 172.16.0.2
PING 100.96.0.16 (100.96.0.16) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 100.96.0.16: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=19.6 ms
64 bytes from 100.96.0.16: icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=13.5 ms
64 bytes from 100.96.0.16: icmp_seq=3 ttl=62 time=13.6 ms
64 bytes from 100.96.0.16: icmp_seq=4 ttl=62 time=13.2 ms
```

###### RPC INFO in client

```
root@client:~/tmp# rpcinfo
   program version netid     address                service    owner
    100000    4    tcp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    3    tcp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    4    udp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    3    udp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    4    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    3    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    2    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    4    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    3    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    2    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    4    local     /run/rpcbind.sock      portmapper superuser
    100000    3    local     /run/rpcbind.sock      portmapper superuser
```